# js bookmarklet that listens for a particular action (in this case submitting a form)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To clarify, I am talking about listening for any action by the web user on any page. The function would then listen for all form submits and delegate to another function when it encounters the form submit url it is looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bookmarklet is just a piece of JavaScript triggered by a user. Just do what you would normally do in order to listen for form submissions ([call `addEventListener` on them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)).

A bookmarklet operates only on the page upon which it is run. You need a browser extension if you want something that will run automatically on every page that the user visits.

Comment: Ah, but the listener needs to already be loaded while the user is browsing. Any way to do this with js? So once the script is loaded it pretty much stays there, listening.

Comment: A bookmarklet operates only on the page upon which it is run. You need a browser extension if you want something that will run automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("FORM");
for (var i = 0, iMax = forms.length; i < iMax; ++i) {
   forms[i].addEventListener("submit", yourFunction, false);
}
```

...should trigger *yourFunction* before any form submitting.